# What happens when a table in a database has more rows than the max size of the index data type?

Tags: database, database-agnostic

For example if i have a unsigned int index in my table, what happens when i get more rows than sizeof(unsigned int) ?
I'm interested in MySQL/PostgreSQL/MsSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks what happens when there are more than 4 or 8 rows (sizeof (unsigned int)).  But I think you mean *What happens when trying to insert a row when there will be 2^32 (or 2^64) rows?*

I've never seen it, and I've worked with some really big databases.  I expect the insert fails and causes the transaction to roll back.  It can be sensed in MySQL with an [insert probe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dba-dtrace-ref-statement.html).